# Working with the body element

Tags: jquery

I have a page (figure below)  with a div#content centered in the body. I want to right-click in the body area, outside of div#content, and read the color there.  If I try

```
 $(document).on("contextmenu", "body", function(el){
      bodyBackgroundColor = $(el).css('background-color');
      debugger;
 });
```

I don't catch the interrupt when I click in the wings.

If I try

```
 $(document).on("contextmenu",function(el){
          bodyBackgroundColor = $(el).css('background-color');
          debugger;
     });
```

I catch the interrupt but with el = document, the $(el).css('background-color') doesn't work.

How should I be doing this?

Thanks.

[image: body element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to get the `background-color` applied on the element where you right-clicked. If so try this.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VjpQ2/)

`el` in the callback is not the element it is the event, you can get the element as `e.target` or even `event.srcElement` would work

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){

         bodyBackgroundColor = $(e.target).css('background-color');
          alert(bodyBackgroundColor);
     });
```

Comment: Thanks. One question, though: When you click in the wings why does e.target come back as html and not body? It was the body element that I assigned the brown color to, not the html element.

Comment: @Steve I am not sure why, probably the height of your body...? See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9EmrT/. Click on body section you will get the color applied on body

Comment: Yes, that was it.  In my body everything is absolutely positioned, so nothing gives it any height. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Sometimes my experience at Stackoverflow is excellent, like this time. Other times my question is marked down (-5 once!) though the question seemed clear to me but probably didn't describe what people usually do with jQuery and the readers were unable to expand their thinking enough to grasp it.  Even though I explained more in comments, they removed the question.  Frustrating . . .  Sorry for the rant.  Thanks again.